# Where can I find the ASP.NET Core 2 source code? Specifically for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect

Tags: asp.net-core, repository, .net-core

I know I can see the (unofficial) source for .Net Core 1 here: https://aspnetsource.azurewebsites.net/

Is there any way to get the official source for the new version?

Does anyone have the exact official Microsoft GitHub URL or another official Microsoft website with the source? I felt this was going to be easy to find, then you look, and the dotnet GitHub repos are a wasteland of unhelpful documentation and no source (in many cases).

Comment: [This](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect) what you're looking for?

Comment: Yup, finally just found it myself. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DotNet Core is a large project spread over several repositories and groups on GitHub. DotNet Core code is available in

**https://github.com/dotnet repos**

while all ASP.NET Core specific code is available in

**https://github.com/aspnet repos**.

The source code which you are looking for is in

**[aspnet/Security](https://github.com/aspnet/Security) repo**.

OpenIdConnect sources are available under the following link:

**[aspnet/Security/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect)**

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @PeterHuber And it asks for third party sources which is specifically not allowed as shown by my quote and a link under the answer. There is a button for us to click for closing such questions for this reason.  If you do not like that, take it up with the Stack Overflow moderators and owners as it is their rule, not mine.

Comment: @Rob - I've not bothered to get involved up to this point, as the information is still here helping people. However, you do realise that I was asking for the official Microsoft source repo which has an exact URL that is not open to debate or opinion? After posting this question I subsequently discovered this well hidden (to me) nugget, as did negacao. He posted the same link I found (as there is only one answer - no opinion involved). Hence when a third person posted the same URL again, I accepted this fact as the right answer. Hope that clears this up.

Comment: @Rob updated the question to make it very clear to everyone that it's only the official Microsoft repo or other website that I was after, re-reading there was possibly some ambiguity (although everyone who responded had the official repo url).

Comment: @Kinetic And again, for the fourth time, in bold, I will highlight why your question is off topic per the shown link to the Help Center: **"Questions asking us to recommend or find a ... off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow..."**

Comment: Do you know where could i find `RouteValueDictionary` in .net core source? none of those github refs contain it. I also find this [.Net Source Code browser](https://source.dot.net) but it dosn't include that class and many other types

Answer (score 11):

After 2 years as this question is opened, I personally found very excellent search fatures to navigate on NET Core sourse code the official web site https://source.dot.net/

You can just search any Type of class, vars, interfaces etc and get in a second the complete source.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This should be proper answer, I was looking for this website exactly.